# What is the error with my python coding?

Tags: python

```
play = input("Would you like to play Steal or Deal [y|n]? ")
if play != "y" or "n":
    print('Please enter either "y" or "n".')
```

regardless of input, the output ends up

```
Would you like to play Steal or Deal [y|n]? y <---- (or "n")
Please enter either "y" or "n".
```

Is there just something I'm missing?

Comment: Shouldn't people start playing if they type 'y'?

Comment: use if play != "y" and play != "n" check. The and check will ensure you go in the if only if play is not y or n, else you will always end up in the if.